# What is the usefulness of a screensaver on a computer using a LCD monitor?

Tags: display, lcd, screensaver

Old computers were using CRT monitors and when an image was continuously displayed on the screen, it became marked. So, screensaver where invented to avoid screen burn-in.

Laptops and modern computers almost all uses LCD display now and, AFAIK, they are not affected by this effect.

So, should I completely deactivate this feature and use power management instead or I am wrong?

Comment: If you know you're going to leave your computer for a while, switch off the LCD yourself will safe a little more energy.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> **What is the usefulness of a screensaver on a computer using a LCD monitor?**

- Entertainment
- Information (rarely IME)
- To prevent you discovering that the brave new modern world (LCD) is
  kinda like the bad old steam-powered world (CRT) in some respects.

If entertainment isn't a use, millions of people have no use for their TVs.

> **Laptops and modern computers almost all uses LCD display now and, AFAIK, they are not affected by this effect.**

http://www.jwz.org/blog/2011/09/xscreensaver-and-gnome-3/

> The little liquid crystals that twist (literally) to move the light around eventually find themselves liking a particular orientation, and tend to stay that way for a bit after they've been requested to do something else. In other words, they act like a tired old man: Capable of moving quickly, but simply unable to do so after being in one position for a long time.

Also

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Screen_burn-in#Plasma.2C_LCD_and_OLED_displays

> Plasma displays are highly susceptible to burn-in, while LCD-type displays are generally less so. Because of the more rapid luminance degradation of current organic compounds used in OLED-type displays, OLED is even more susceptible to burn-in than plasma.[citation needed] In addition, the wide variation in luminance degradation with OLED [1] will cause noticeable color drift over time (where one of the red-green-blue colors becomes more prominent).
>
> In the case of LCDs, the mechanics of burn-in are different than plasma and OLED, which develop burn-in from luminance degradation of the light-emitting pixels. For LCDs, burn-in develops in some cases because pixels permanently lose their ability to return to their relaxed state after a continued static usage profile. In more typical usage profiles this image persistence in LCD is only transient.

---

> **So, should I completely deactivate this feature and use power management instead**

In order to save yourself, your equipment and your planet, you should probably turn everything off and unplug it all when not using it.

---

> **or I am wrong?**

Not much IMHO, despite the above.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to go for power efficiency, I would recommend to, like you stated, use power management to turn the screen off when it's not used for a while. If you don't care about efficiency and you like the effects screensavers can give, you can still use it.

Comment: I somehow agree with you just because LCD can be switched on so quick and barely need to warm up.